# Visual Studio IDE confused about meaning of var keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, var, implicit-typing

Consider the following simple program:

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
  }

  static void Method(short? x)
  {
    const int y = 50; // note: is Int32, but is const and within Int16 range
    var z = x ?? y;   // note: var keyword used; IDE is confused about the type!
    TakeOnlyInt16(z);
    z.OnThisInt16();
  }

  static void TakeOnlyInt16(short a)
  {
  }
  static void OnThisInt16(this short a)
  {
  }
}
```

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this program, and it compiles with no problem.
(And you can run it, possibly including a call to `Method` from `Main`.)

However, the Visual Studio [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) has a wrong impression of the type of the local variable `z`. It seems to think `z` is an `Int32` when it is actually an `Int16` (a.k.a. `short` in C#). The problem shows in at least three situations:

1. When you "hover" over (hold mouse over) the `var` keyword, it shows you `Int32` in a tooltip. That is wrong.
2. When you move the text (keyboard) cursor to within the statement `TakeOnlyInt16(z);` inside `Method`, it shows a little tip in the lower left corner of this statement, offering to "Generate method stub for `TakeOnlyInt16` in `Program`". That is wrong because the method is clearly already there. But it seems to think the overload already present is wrong wrt. `short` and `int`.
3. When you type `z.` (zed dot) inside `Method`, the members of `Int32` come up in *intellisense*. Note that the overloads of `CompareTo` are the ones declared by `Int32`, not the ones declared by `Int16`. Also, the extension method is missing from the intellisense member list, when you type `z.`.

Hope you understand my explanations without screenshots.

**The question:** Where does this bug come from? Is it well-known? Is it in older versions of Visual Studio as well?

I tried this in VS2013.

Comment: I'm not sure the IDE has done the optimization of making y a short. It probably looks at it it's type and the type of x and chooses the one that is broader.

Comment: Nothing we can do about it, best place to report bugs like this is connect.microsoft.com

Comment: My terminology is shaky here, but I believe an implicit widening conversion is happening since y is an int32. I would not expect '??' to be defined for `(int16, int32)` but it's usually permitted to upcast x to int implicitly. In other words, not a bug.

Comment: @Prescott The compile-time type of `y` must be `int`, and the compile-time type of `z` must be `short`. Overload resolution etc. must correspond to this fact. This is not about optimization. It is about the correct "formal" type of `z`. (Optimization would be if the runtime chose to represent one of the numbers in another way internally. We don't care about that. As long as the program works as required.)

Comment: @TomW No, `z` is a `short`. How would the next two statements be legal if `z` were an `int`? There exists an _implicit_ narrowing conversion from `int` to `short` when (and only when) it is a constant expression (compile-time literal) and the value is within the range of the destination type. See my comment to JotaBe's answer.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't noticed the signatures of the following lines. I answered in a rush while at work, so that can serve as a clear example of why implicit conversion **is not** the answer. I stand corrected.

Comment: @TomW To repeat myself from comments elsewhere: What many people forget is that an [implicit constant expression conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691286.aspx) exists **from** `int` **to** `short` when the `int` expression is a compile-time constant _and_ the numeric value of that `int` is within the range of the destination type `short`. (I guess I should have mentioned that in my question, but I thought it was clear from the context that `z` was a `short`.) So this ***is*** about implicit conversions, but they are _constant_ conversions.

Answer (score 2):

[According to C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx), the null-coalescing operator (??)

> is used to define a default value for nullable value types or
>   reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is
>   not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

If the right hand operand is `int`, and the left operand, when not null, is `short`, the compiler has to choose between `int` and `short`. And, as `short` can be implicitly converted to `int` (and not viceversa) the compiler correctly decides that the result of this expression is of `int` type.

Still not convinced? Why couldn't it be the other way round?. Mmmm, let's see what says the [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), 7.13:

> The type of the expression a ?? b depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of a ?? b is A0, A, or B, where A is the type of a (provided that a has a type), B is the type of b (provided that b has a type), and A0 is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise.

If you still want to ignore the "implicit conversions available" part, as this could lead to think it should be A0 (short), let's keep on reading the spec:

> Specifically, a ?? b is processed as follows:
>
> •If A exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> •If b is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is converted to dynamic, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated, and this becomes the result.
>
> •Otherwise, if A exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from b to A0, the result type is A0. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A0, and this becomes the result.
>   *NOTE: this is not the case, there is no conversion from b (int) to A0 (short)*
>
> •Otherwise, if A exists and an implicit conversion exists from b to A, the result type is A. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A, and this becomes the result.
>
> **•Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and becomes the result.**
>   *NOTE: this is the case*
>
> •Otherwise, a and b are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.

So, no, the compiler is not buggy. You're making a wrong assumption.

Comment: Thank you for quoting very relevant parts of the C# specification! Note that `b` (which is called `y` in my example) is **`const`** of type `int`. There does exist an [implicit constant expression conversion (see the C# Spec)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691286.aspx) **from** `int` **to** `short`. Therefore, in my case, there exist implicit conversions both from `b` to `A0` _and_ from `a` to `B`. So from the quotes you give yourself, the type of the `??` expression is `A0`. That is the underlying type of `A`. `A` is `short?`, so `A0` is plain `short`. So the type is `short`.

Comment: Please try my code. If `z` were not a `short`, the two next statements could never compile ...

Comment: I'll try your code. I overlooked that important detail. It makes it more interesting. Perhaps there is a nuance between implicit type conversion and constant value conversion. Which C# or Framework version are you using? Probably the debugger, or ILDASM will give a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees:

```
const int y = 50; // note: is Int32, but is const and within Int16 range
var z = x ?? y;   // note: var keyword used; IDE is confused about the type!
```

and knows that `y` is of type `int`, whether or not it is `const`. This being the case, `z` is assumed to be `Int32` as it is the bigger type.

If you are looking to make `z` of type `short`, try:

```
const int y = 50; // note: is Int32, but is const and within Int16 range
var z = x ?? (short)y;   // note: var keyword used; IDE is confused about the type!
```

Comment: You do realize that `z` was a `short` already in the first example? You are right that it is OK to write the (otherwise implicit) cast explicitly, as in `(short)y`, and in that case VS is not confused. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I thought we were talking about when you hover over the variable in the IDE? When you do this, it says it is of type `int`, like you described before.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compiler optimization that maybe the editor is not able to show.

For example:

```
short? x = 44;
const int y = int.MaxValue;
var z = x ?? y;

var t = z.GetType(); //Int32
```

in this case the compiler realizes that `z` may end up containing a value that will not fit in an Int16 so it will declare `z` as an Int32.

in this other example:

```
short? x = 44;
const int y = 33;
var z = x ?? y;

var t = z.GetType(); //Int16
```

the compiler realizes that `z` will contain a value that will always fit in an Int16 so it will declare `z` as an Int16

Comment: You are right the _implicit constant expression conversion_ from `Int32` to `Int16` exists only if the constant in question is within the range of the destination type, `Int16`. That is why I wrote in the code comment that `50` is in that range. This is not a "compiler optimization". The compiler is not allowed to mess with types. For example `y.GetType()` is required to always give `Int32` no matter how tiny `y` is. The important thing is whether an *implicit* conversion exists from `y` to `short`.